# Как сделать класс, чтобы вызывать его методы без создания объекта в другом классе

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть класс:

```
export default class PinBot extends SlackActions {/* */}
```

Его метод вызывается из другого класса так:

```
static pinBot = new PinBot();
this.pinBot.method();
```

Можно ли как-то через пространство имен сделать чтобы этот метод вызывался без `static pinBot = new PinBot();`

Comment: в зачем тебе static?

Comment: вызывается статический метод

Comment: Приведи пример твоего кода, то что сейчас в вопросе можно и без static

Comment: В вопросе имел ввиду использование не без слова static, а создание глобальной переменной pinBot

Comment: Ты можешь экспортировать из модуля объект класса, а не класс